# How can I know which file system is used for my internal storage?

Tags: file-system, ext4, exfat

I want to know whether my internal storage is formatted as exFAT, FAT32, ext4, etc.

How can I tell?

I run rooted Android 5.0, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need either access via [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) (`adb shell`) or a [terminal app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_992). At the prompt, execute

```
mount | grep "/data"
```

The output will have something like

```
/emmc@usrdata /data ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
```

The third column tells you the file system used (in the example above: `ext4`).

Of course there are also several 3rd party apps offering you such insight :)

Comment: Thanks! And the output said `ext4` :D :D :D No more silly 4 GB limit :)